# iptables -I FORWARD -j DROP does not cut existing connections

Tags: iptables, openwrt

I have a router with openwrt. I want to temporarily cut all transit traffic without changing the router's configuration. I do this:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -j DROP
```

New connections cannot be established now. But existing connections (even `ping`) continue to work.  How can I make `iptables` stop existing connections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

specific versions of `OpenWRT` have a performance optimization enabled. This turns it off:

```
sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_skip_filter=0
```

http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/firewall#nf_conntrack_skip_filter

Comment: As stated on the provided link:  "Only available in Barrier Breaker. Revoked in Chaos Calmer RC1 and onwards due to various problems.".  Thus on more recent version of OpenWrt, this option is not available.  If anybody knows I to perform the blocking, please share with the community.

Comment: @HansDeragon just use the command from the question

Comment: root@OpenWrt:~# sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_skip_filter=0
sysctl: error: 'net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_skip_filter' is an unknown key

Comment: `iptables -D delegate_forward -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` is one way, but this disabling it manually.  I want the rule to be removed all the time.  I want to be able to block my kids connections any the time, while keeping mine going.  It seams that this is a feature missing within OpenWrt.

Comment: @HansDeragon The closest thing in the router's web UI is `Network - Firewall - Traffic Rules` You can create forward rules there with the Mac addresses (yours or others), set or clear the "enabled" checkbox and press "save & apply"

Comment: I am doing this from the UI but when I want to cut my kids connections, they remain because they are already established; the iptables rule remains.  I noticed that if I removed the rule as I suggested, all connections are not maintained, breaking my own connections and the Internet becomes inaccessible.  It must remain in service, but I believe it must be moved downward the `delegate_forward` chain.  I will test this later.

Answer (score -1):

Try with
`# iptables -i FORWARD 1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j DROP`

**Updated**

I have not experienced this kind scenario before, but think matching particular connection state we could achieve what you want.

*Options are;*

`--state ESTABLISHED` = connections already established,

`--state NEW` = consider connections going to be start

Comment: Can you expand on why that would work? It doesn't make sense to me. I thought the OP's command ought to causes every packet to be dropped, unconditionally, regardless of `ESTABLISHED` state and indeed regardless of anything else.